# fileExistsAtPath: (NSFileManager)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Is this method supposed to take a path as its argument?

It looks like it takes a filename as a path:

For example, /home/file.txt is a file, while /home/ is a path. This method looks like it takes the former as an argument.

Comment: By convention the method parameter's name tells you what it expects by putting the input last. In this case, it's file_at_Path, so it expects a path. By contrast, something like path_for_fileName would expect a string containing a file name and would return a path.

Comment: Why the downvote? Code examples show that a file name is being passed.

Comment: Not the down-voter here, but it's likely due to a combination of the subject and first sentence. You should take care to ask more complete questions with more precise subjects, etc.

Comment: @Joshua Nozzi: How is it possible to get more precise than "does fileExistsAtPath: take a path as an argument?  It seems to me that it was downvoted because the questioner has a false understanding of what a path is.  I don't think that is a legitimate reason for a down vote.

Comment: You're arguing with the wrong person. I said I'm not the down-voter, but was speculating. The subject of the question is vague and first sentence is answered by the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your distinction of "path" vs. "file" is not one that is common in Unix. Whether the final element of a path is a file or not doesn't affect the fact that it is a path. "/home/file.txt" looks like an absolute file path (though it could in fact be a deceptively named directory). "/home/" is an absolute directory path. Both are paths. (So is "foo/bar" — would you call that a "file" or a "path" in your terminology? Without inspecting the object at that path, we can't know whether it names a directory or a file.) Apple is using the term in its normal sense.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it takes a string that is a path - see the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-CHDDDDJG):

> **Parameters**
>   *path*
>   The path of a file or directory. If path begins with a tilde (`~`), it must first be expanded with `stringByExpandingTildeInPath`, or this method returns `NO`.

Note that `/home/file.txt` *is a path*, just like `/home/`. The former however is no *directory*, while the latter is.

Comment: It looks like it takes a filename not a path

Comment: Why would you think it does? The parameter is even named `path`.

Comment: The parameter is named path but the code that I'm looking at is passing a file name.

Comment: I thought that a path the directory where the file resides.

Comment: No, paths can identify both files and directories, see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29): *"A path, the general form of a filename or of a directory name, specifies a unique location in a file system."*

Comment: awakeFromNib: A filename is just that: A name of a file. It also functions as a relative pathname. A pathname can be absolute or relative; a relative pathname is relative to the current working directory, while an absolute pathname is just that: A complete pathname of something in the file-system. Note that a relative pathname can consist of only a single component (a name) and an absolute pathname can consist of no components at all (just /, the root directory), and any pathname can refer to a file, directory, something else, or nothing at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to look for distinctions between files and folders, see [-fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:).

Usage:

```
BOOL isDirectory;
if ([self fileExistsAtPath:@"/Users/me/Subfolder" isDirectory:&isDirectory] && isDirectory)
{
    // Exists and is a directory. Isn't that neat?
}
```